# Need to pass complex type data from HTML form

Tags: html, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have few wsdl files which talks to my servers. I developed one html page which sends data to wsdl and wsdl converts the data in a server request format and returns the response as soap xml. As all the text field were accepting string values so i didn't face any problem. But now i came across one complex type in wsdl named as StringOrderedCollection. Below is the code for that:

```
<xsd:complexType name="StringOrderedCollection">
     <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:restriction base="enc:Array">
            <xsd:attribute ref="enc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
         </xsd:restriction>
     </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

and the atrribute wsdl is accepting as :

```
<wsdl:message name="FwReasonCodeMatchAnyTxnRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="categories" type="btl:StringOrderedCollection"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

Could any suggest me how to use html page for this case if user has to input data in textfield? I am very new to this so hope experts can help me here. Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Hi, is it possible to store the array in a variable and pass that variable as an input to the form?